# $r(M)$-subsets of a 3-connected matroid $M$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matroid-theory

It is proved in [Lowrance, Oxley, Semple, and Welsh - On properties of almost all matroids](https://digitalcommons.lsu.edu/mathematics_pubs/1205) that almost all matroids are 3-connected asymptotically. Also, it is conjectured that almost all matroids are sparse paving. The latter conjecture is proved logarithmically in [Pendavingh and van der Pol - On the number of bases of almost all matroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04763). There is a characterization for $r(M)$-subsets of a sparse paving matroid $M$ that is every $r(M)$-subset is either a basis or very close to being a basis (circuit- hyperplane). Since both classes of 3-connected matroids and sparse paving matroids are very large families of matroids I have the impression that they must have a large intersection, and probably one may claim that for a 3-connected matroid $M$, most of $r(M)$-subsets are kind of close to being a basis, if not a basis. Is there any result or evidence supporting this?

Comment: For a cycle matroid of a complete graph, $r(M)$-subsets seem to be mostly quite far from spanning trees.